# Getting rid of grub on Windows 10

Tags: grub2, windows

I am trying to get rid of grub on my Asus Ultrabook. I have removed the partitions containing Ubuntu 16.04 and merged them back into the main Windows partition. I have looked into methods of getting rid of it, but none seem to work. The computer has no optical drive, so I cannot use a recovery disk. I can access Windows by exiting out of grub but I plan to give the laptop to my parents and they won't really want to type exit every time they want to use the laptop.

Thanks!

Comment: If UEFI, you need to remove the /EFI/ubuntu folder in the ESP - efi system partition and then remove the entries in UEFI with efibootmgr. Do not know how to do from Windows. Uninstall Ubuntu from menu, Really UEFI boot menu 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi

Answer (score 0):

You can load windows onto a usb stick with the Windows USB/DVD Download tool at the link below, and do a boot repair. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool